# Python to read a File with start and stop condition

Tags: regex, linux, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a below File data, which i'm looking to process to get the Expected output, just curious to know as a python learner if there is way to achieve this based on start and stop Boolean index.

Here in a file line startswith a string called `SRV:` always though these line in some cases starts and ends at the same line whereas these gets expanded into newline in some cases.

### File text Data :

```
SRV: this is for bryan

SRV: this is for terry

SRV: this is for torain
sec01: This is reserved
sec02: This is open for all
sec03: Closed!

SRV: this is for Jun
```

### Expected Output:

```
SRV: this is for bryan

SRV: this is for terry

SRV: this is for torain sec01: This is reserved sec02: This is open for all sec03: Closed!

SRV: this is for Jun
```

Is there a Pythonic way to achieve this in a better way, i'm okay with pandas as well.

Comment: you can try with something like `df[0].groupby(df[0].str.startswith('SRV').cumsum()).apply(' '.join)` , where `0` is the column name. (Note: this is using a pandas dataframe)

Comment: @anky_91, this works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for groups and then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join`:

```
df1 = (df['col'].groupby(df['col'].str.startswith('SRV').cumsum())
                .agg(' '.join)
                .reset_index(drop=True)
                .to_frame(name='new'))
print (df1)
                                                 new
0                             SRV: this is for bryan
1                             SRV: this is for terry
2  SRV: this is for torain sec01: This is reserve...
3                               SRV: this is for Jun
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col'].str.startswith('SRV').cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    4
Name: col, dtype: int32
```

For `DataFrame` use:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""col
SRV: this is for bryan

SRV: this is for terry

SRV: this is for torain
sec01: This is reserved
sec02: This is open for all
sec03: Closed!

SRV: this is for Jun"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="|")

print (df)
                           col
0       SRV: this is for bryan
1       SRV: this is for terry
2      SRV: this is for torain
3      sec01: This is reserved
4  sec02: This is open for all
5               sec03: Closed!
6         SRV: this is for Jun
```

Pure python solution:

```
out = []
with open("file.csv") as f1:
        last = 0
        for i, line in enumerate(f1.readlines()):
            if line.strip().startswith('SRV'):
                last = i
            out.append([line.strip(), last])

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open("out_file.csv", "w") as f2:
    groups = groupby(out, key=itemgetter(1))
    for _, g in groups:
        gg = list(g)
        h = ' '.join(list(map(itemgetter(0), gg)))
        f2.write('\n' + h)
```

Comment: this is indeed great @-jezrael +1

Comment: @-jezrael, can you explain how it remembers that it has to hold the data until it sees next `srv` ?

Comment: @user294110 - Added also pure python solution in edited answer.